# Accordion different Behavior when running on Staging

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, accordion

I'm currently developing a website using Ruby-on-rails. I have included the accordion on my form.

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion no-margin">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a href="#accordion-ci" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
        <i class="icon-th"></i>
              COMMERCIAL ITEM
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="accordion-ci" style="height: auto;">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
            <!--
              revised by: hansen.salim@nutrifood.co.id, August 31st 2017
              adding id to connect to JS for drag n drop
            -->
              <!--<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">-->
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin" id="sortable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:20%">ITEM DESCRIPTION</th>
              <th style="width:20%">SECONDARY ITEM DESCRIPTION</th>
              <th style="width:10%">PRICE</th>
              <th style="width:8%">PRICE ON MASTER</th>
              <th style="width:8%">QUANTITY</th>
              <th style="width:9%">VOLUME (CBM)</th>
              <th style="width:9%">WEIGHT (KG)</th>
              <th style="width:10%">TOTAL FOB (USD)</th>
              <th style="width:6%">ACTION</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="ci">
            <%= render partial: 'item_detail', collection: @ci_products %>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="9">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="add_buyer_sales_contract_detail btn btn-success" data-icon=""></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been testing the website running locally using `localhost:3000`. The result come out nicely, the accordion will show the form when the header is clicked. Then I'm going to test it at Staging phase. I have push to the server and then precompile it and `rake assets:clean`.

And then the problem arise, I tested the accordion, but it doesn't show the form like it's supposed to. I tried to something like this to check :

```
    show: function () {
      var dimension
        , scroll
        , actives
        , hasData

      if (this.transitioning) return

      dimension = this.dimension()
      scroll = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))
      actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .accordion-group > .in')

      this.$element[dimension](0)
      this.transition('addClass', $.Event('show'), 'shown')
      $.support.transition && this.$element[dimension](this.$element[0][scroll])
      alert("Open")
      return this
    }

  , hide: function () {
      var dimension
      if (this.transitioning) return
      dimension = this.dimension()
      this.reset(this.$element[dimension]())
      this.transition('removeClass', $.Event('hide'), 'hidden')
      this.$element[dimension](0)
      alert("Hide")
      return this
    }
```

This is the collapse function that implemented the accordion. I tried to add the alert to check if the javascript and jquery worked. When I tested it again at my Staging, after I clicked on the header, Alert "Hide" worked (because the default that form is open) and then another Alert "Open" popped up. It seems that both the

```
 hide()
```

and

```
 show()
```

function worked simultaneously. I had no idea why this would occur while my Local is working perfectly.